# Balancing a Jagged array/List while mainting order in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I have a list of objects `List<object>`, each object has a length associated with it. I can then have multiple of these lists of objects and I want to put them into another list or array with a certain count. Order matters and I need every element in the top level list to have at least one list in it.

example:

```
list<object> myList1;  myList1 count is 4

List<object> myList2;  myList2 count is 3

List<object> myList3;  myList3 count is 1

List<object> myList4;  myList4 count is 20
```

put all those into an array with 3 elements (balanced as much as possible)

the good outcome would be `[myList1] [myList2,myList3] [myList4]`

the problem is that the list with count 20 throws off any averaging I could do and I have to keep the list in order. Is there an approach or algorithm I can use?

Comment: can you maybe show a bit of your code?

Comment: It's not particularly clear, but it sounds like this is the knapsack problem, or one of it's variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a greedy algorithm. First I started with my target length then added to each list as much as possible without going over. Then I used a while loop to check if I had too many Elements in my top level list, if i did I then increased the target and started over.

```
double targetLength = System.Math.Round(totalLinecount / (double)displayColumnCount);

while (result.Count != displayColumnCount)
{
    result = new List<List<MenuItem>>();
    result.Add(new List<MenuItem>());
    foreach (MenuItem menuItem in menuItems)
    {
        int currentLength = result.Last().Count == 0 ? 0 : result.Last().Sum(s => s.TotalLength);
        if (result.Last().Count == 0 || (currentLength + menuItem.TotalLength) <= targetLength)
        {
            result.Last().Add(menuItem);
        }
        else
            result.Add(new List<MenuItem> { menuItem });
        }
        targetLength++;
        if (result.Count <= displayColumnCount) 
        break;
    }
}
```